# I can not find a way to deal with new pages in docx using Python

Tags: python, docx

I have a docx file with 40 pages of text and I want to separate each page and import its context into a list. Is this possible? The only way I have found is to find the empty spots in my list but that does not always mean a page break. With my code I get the text after the word "Subject" is found and it stops
after a blank spot is found. The thing is that need a way to recognise pagebreak in my code to solve some issues. This way page break is also being treated as a " " . Thanks in advance

```
import os
import docx


def read(name):
    doc = docx.Document(name)

    text =[]

    for par in doc.paragraphs:
        text.append(par.text)

    return text

''''''
for basename in os.listdir('files'):
    path = os.path.join('files', basename)
    jerk = read(path)
lari =[]
vaccum = []
indices = []
for i in jerk:
    if not i.find('Subject'):
        lari.append(jerk.index(i))
    indices.append(jerk.index(i))

for j in jerk:
    if jerk.index(j) in lari:
        for k in range(20):
            if jerk[jerk.index(j)+k]!='':
                vaccum.append(jerk[jerk.index(j) + k + 1])

            else:
                break
final =[]
var =''
for k in vaccum:
    var = var+k
    if k =='':
        final.append(var)
        var =''

print(vaccum)
```

Comment: Word documents don't *have*  pages unless the author has inserted a page break, which might be specified in the paragraph style rather than as an explicit page break. This is what most people want. If you change the paper from Letter to A4, the text will automatically reflow and this page boundaries will change. So pages are mostly an attribute of a particular rendering of the document, and not of the document itself.